# d3js timeline chart - with one rectangle block for a scrub

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am looking at creating a timeline chart with only one rectangle block at the bottom. That's used as a master scrubber.

//current - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/2427/

[image]

where the scrubbing section is - I want to have just a base rectangle. What kind of modifications should I make to the current code base

so its more like this
[image]

//my latest - https://jsfiddle.net/2mvhjr7z/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var $this = $('.timelinechart');
    
      var w = $this.data("width");
      var h = $this.data("height");
      //var data = $this.data("data");

      
    var data = [
      {
        "label": "person a",
        "icon": "4",
        "times": [
          {"text": "Test 1", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000},
          {"text": "Test 2", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000},
          {"text": "Test 6", "starting_time": 1355761900000, "ending_time": 1355764520000},
          {"text": "Test 7", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000}
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "person b",
        "icon": "5",
        "times": [
          {"text": "Test 8", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000},
          {"text": "Test 9", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000},
          {"text": "Test 10", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355867900000}
        ]
      }
    ];


    var lanes = [];
    var times = [];
    var icons = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      lanes.push(value.label);
      //icons.push(_avatarList[value.icon].image);
      $.each(value.times, function(i, v) {
        v["lane"] = index;
      });
      times.push(value.times); 
    });

    var laneLength = lanes.length;
    var items = [].concat.apply([], times);

    $.each(items, function(i, v) {
      v["id"] = i;
    });

    var timeBegin = d3.min(items, function(d) { return d["starting_time"]; });
    var timeEnd = d3.max(items, function(d) { return d["ending_time"]; });

    var m = [25, 80, 15, 105], //top right bottom left 
      w = w - m[1] - m[3],
      h = h - m[0] - m[2],
      miniHeight = laneLength * 12 + 50,
      mainHeight = h - miniHeight - 50;

    //scales
    var x =  d3.scaleTime()
        .range([0, w])    
        .domain([timeBegin, timeEnd]);
    var x1 = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, w]);
    var y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, mainHeight])
        .domain([0, laneLength]);
    var y2 = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, miniHeight])
        .domain([0, laneLength]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
      .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
      .tickFormat(d=>d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d));


    var scaleFactor = (1/(timeEnd - timeBegin)) * (w);

    var chartWidth = w + m[1] + m[3];
    var chartHeight = h + m[0] + m[2];

    var chart = d3.select($this[0])
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", chartWidth)
          .attr("height", chartHeight)
          .attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+chartWidth+" "+chartHeight)
          .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "timelinechartg");
    
    chart.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", mainHeight);

    var main = chart.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", mainHeight)
          .attr("class", "main");

    var mini = chart.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + m[0]) + ")")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", miniHeight)
          .attr("class", "mini");


    var gX = chart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + miniHeight) + ")")
          .call(xAxis); 
          
    //background colors
    function colores_background(n) {
      var colores_g = ["#f8dd2f", "#e9168a", "#448875", "#2b2d39", "#c3bd75", "#1b91dc"];
      return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
    }

    //foreground colors
    function colores_foreground(n) {
      var colores_g = ["#553814", "#311854", "#f7b363", "#c12f39", "#89191d", "#2b2d39"];
      return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
    }

    //main lanes and texts
    main.append("g").selectAll(".laneLines")
      .data(items)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", function(d) {return y1(d.lane);})
      .attr("x2", w)
      .attr("y2", function(d) {return y1(d.lane);})
      .attr("stroke", "lightgray")

        var defs = main.append('svg:defs');

    main.append("g").selectAll(".laneText")
      .data(lanes)
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) {return d;})
      .attr("x", (-m[1] + 10))
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return y1(i + .5);
      })
      .attr("dy", ".5ex")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("class", "laneText");

    //mini lanes and texts
    mini.append("g").selectAll(".laneLines")
      .data(items)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return y2(d.lane);
      })
      .attr("x2", w)
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return y2(d.lane);
      })
      .attr("stroke", "lightgray");

    mini.append("g").selectAll(".laneText")
      .data(lanes)
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) {return d;})
      .attr("x", -m[1] + 40)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {return y2(i + .5);})
      .attr("dy", ".5ex")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("class", "laneText");

    var itemRects = main.append("g")
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
        
    //mini item rects
    mini.append("g").selectAll("miniItems")
      .data(items)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) {return "miniItem "+d.state;})
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.starting_time);})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return y2(d.lane + .5) - 5;})
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colores_background(d.lane);
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return (d.ending_time - d.starting_time) * scaleFactor;
      })
      .attr("height", 10);

    //mini labels
    mini.append("g").selectAll(".miniLabels")
      .data(items)
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) {return d.text;})
      .attr("class", function(d) {return d.state;})
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.starting_time);})
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y2(d.lane + .5);
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colores_foreground(d.lane);
      })
      .attr("dy", ".5ex");

    $.each(icons, function(index, value) {
      defs.append('svg:pattern')
        .attr('id', "--"+index)
        .attr('width', 1)
        .attr('height', 1)
        .append('svg:image')
        .attr('image-rendering', "optimizeQuality")
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet")
        .attr('xlink:href', value)
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', 50)
        .attr('height', 50);

      defs.append('svg:pattern')
        .attr('id', "--m"+index)
        .attr('width', 1)
        .attr('height', 1)
        .append('svg:image')
        .attr('image-rendering', "optimizeQuality")
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet")
        .attr('xlink:href', value)
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', 20)
        .attr('height', 20);  

      main.append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate("+(-m[1] + 5)+","+ (y1(index + .5) - 50) +")";
        })
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "user")
          .style("stroke", "gray")
          .style("fill", "url(#--"+index+")")
          .attr("r", 25)
          .attr("cx", 40)
          .attr("cy", 50);

      mini.append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate("+(-m[1] + 40)+","+ (y2(index + .5) - 20) +")";
        })
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "user")
          .style("stroke", "gray")
          .style("fill", "url(#--m"+index+")")
          .attr("r", 10)
          .attr("cx", 20)
          .attr("cy", 20);
    });

    var brush = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[0, 0], [w, miniHeight]])
        .on("brush", brushed);

    mini.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
      .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", 1)
      .attr("height", miniHeight - 1); 

    function brushed() {
      var selection = d3.event.selection;
      var timeSelection = selection.map(x.invert, x);
      //console.log("selection: " + selection);
      //console.log("start: " + timeSelection[0]);
      //console.log("end: " + timeSelection[1]);
      
      var rects;
      var labels;
      var minExtent = timeSelection[0];
      var maxExtent = timeSelection[1];    
      
      var visItems = items.filter(function(d) {return d.starting_time <  maxExtent && d.ending_time > minExtent;});
    
        //mini.select(".brush")
          //.call(brush.extent([minExtent, maxExtent]));          
          
        x1.domain([minExtent, maxExtent]);      
        
        //update main item rects
        rects = itemRects.selectAll("rect")
                .data(visItems, function(d) { return d.id; })
            .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.starting_time);})
            .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);});
        
        rects.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d) {return "miniItem "+d.state;})
          .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.starting_time);})
          .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane) + 10;})
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return colores_background(d.lane);
          })
          .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);})
          .attr("height", function(d) {return .8 * y1(1);});

        rects.exit().remove();

        //update the item labels
        labels = itemRects.selectAll("text")
          .data(visItems, function (d) { return d.id; })
          .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(Math.max(d.starting_time, minExtent) + 2);});

        labels.enter().append("text")
          .text(function(d) {return d.text;})
          .attr("class", function(d) {return d.state;})
          .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(Math.max(d.starting_time, minExtent));})
          .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane + .5);})
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return colores_foreground(d.lane);
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", "start");

        labels.exit().remove();
    }

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#holder {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*
.chart {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
*/

.timelinechart{
  /*width:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.timelinechart svg{
  width:100%;
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
}

.timelinechartg{
  
}

.mini text {
  font: 10px sans-serif; 
}

.main text {
  font: 12px sans-serif; 
}

.miniItem {
  /*fill: darksalmon;*/
  stroke-width: 6; 
}

.miniItem.future{
  fill: #448875;
}
text.future {
  fill: #f7b363;
}


.brush .extent {
  stroke: #b6b8b9;
  fill: #57585b;
  fill-opacity: .365;
  stroke-width: .2;
}

.laneImg{
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="timelinechart" data-role="timelinechart" data-width=500 data-height=300 data-data="" ></div>
```

---

latest design is like this
[image]

and as the scrubber shows more detail - like a 1 month date range -- the format of the scale becomes more detailed
[image]

Comment: Hi, I didn't get what you want to do, do you want to remove 'person p' section from the chart?

Comment: just have a single rectangle - a generic scrubber -- rather than a mini version of the main chart

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/2mvhjr7z/2/

Comment: do you mean to remove the yellow and pink bars and keep a thin small line like the one in provided fiddle?

Comment: yes - something like this -- https://jsfiddle.net/KgomDr/46uLtcvf/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2y8gkas3/7/  -- latest example --

Answer (score 3):

Though I am not clear about what exactly you want to achieve, I assume you need to have generic base rectangle.

I have removed the line of code to display the label of this base rectangle and have updated the height of the mini section.

Let me know if this is not what you are expecting.

Kindly review my fiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var $this = $('.timelinechart');
  
     var w = $this.data("width");
     var h = $this.data("height");
     //var data = $this.data("data");

     
  var data = [
   {
    "label": "person a",
    "icon": "4",
    "times": [
     {"text": "Test 1", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000},
     {"text": "Test 2", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000},
     {"text": "Test 6", "starting_time": 1355761900000, "ending_time": 1355764520000},
     {"text": "Test 7", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000}
    ]
   },
      {
    "label": "person b",
    "icon": "5",
    "times": [
     {"text": "Test 8", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000},
     {"text": "Test 9", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000},
     {"text": "Test 10", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355867900000}
    ]
   }
  ];


  var lanes = [];
  var times = [];
  var icons = [];
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
   lanes.push(value.label);
   //icons.push(_avatarList[value.icon].image);
   $.each(value.times, function(i, v) {
    v["lane"] = index;
   });
   times.push(value.times); 
  });

  var laneLength = lanes.length;
  var items = [].concat.apply([], times);

  $.each(items, function(i, v) {
   v["id"] = i;
  });

  var timeBegin = d3.min(items, function(d) { return d["starting_time"]; });
  var timeEnd = d3.max(items, function(d) { return d["ending_time"]; });

  var m = [25, 80, 15, 105], //top right bottom left 
   w = w - m[1] - m[3],
   h = h - m[0] - m[2],
   miniHeight = laneLength * 12 + 25,
   mainHeight = h - miniHeight - 50;

  //scales
  var x =  d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, w])    
    .domain([timeBegin, timeEnd]);
  var x1 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, w]);
  var y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, mainHeight])
    .domain([0, laneLength]);
  var y2 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, miniHeight])
    .domain([0, laneLength]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
    .tickFormat(d=>d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d));


  var scaleFactor = (1/(timeEnd - timeBegin)) * (w);

  var chartWidth = w + m[1] + m[3];
  var chartHeight = h + m[0] + m[2];

  var chart = d3.select($this[0])
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", chartWidth)
     .attr("height", chartHeight)
     .attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+chartWidth+" "+chartHeight)
     .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "timelinechartg");
  
  chart.append("defs").append("clipPath")
   .attr("id", "clip")
   .append("rect")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", mainHeight);

  var main = chart.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", mainHeight)
     .attr("class", "main");

  var mini = chart.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + m[0]) + ")")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", miniHeight)
     .attr("class", "mini");


  var gX = chart.append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + miniHeight) + ")")
     .call(xAxis); 
     
  //background colors
  function colores_background(n) {
   var colores_g = ["#f8dd2f", "#e9168a", "#448875", "#2b2d39", "#c3bd75", "#1b91dc"];
   return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
  }

  //foreground colors
  function colores_foreground(n) {
   var colores_g = ["#553814", "#311854", "#f7b363", "#c12f39", "#89191d", "#2b2d39"];
   return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
  }
 
  main.append("g").selectAll(".laneText")
   .data(lanes)
   .enter().append("text")
   .text(function(d) {return d;})
   .attr("x", (-m[1] + 10))
   .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return y1(i + .5);
   })
   .attr("dy", ".5ex")
   .attr("text-anchor", "end")
   .attr("class", "laneText");

  //main lanes and texts
  main.append("g").selectAll(".laneLines")
   .data(items)
   .enter().append("line")
   .attr("x1", 0)
   .attr("y1", function(d) {return y1(d.lane);})
   .attr("x2", w)
   .attr("y2", function(d) {return y1(d.lane);})
   .attr("stroke", "lightgray")

        var defs = main.append('svg:defs');

    

  var itemRects = main.append("g")
       .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
    
  mini.append('rect')
  .attr("class", "miniBar")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("fill", "grey")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", 30);
  

 

  var brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([[0, 0], [w, miniHeight]])
      .on("brush", brushed);

  mini.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x brush")
   .call(brush)
   .selectAll("rect")
   .attr("y", 1)
   .attr("height", miniHeight - 1); 

  function brushed() {
    var selection = d3.event.selection;
    var timeSelection = selection.map(x.invert, x);
    //console.log("selection: " + selection);
    //console.log("start: " + timeSelection[0]);
    //console.log("end: " + timeSelection[1]);
    
   var rects;
   var labels;
   var minExtent = timeSelection[0];
   var maxExtent = timeSelection[1];    
    
    var visItems = items.filter(function(d) {return d.starting_time <  maxExtent && d.ending_time > minExtent;});
   
    //mini.select(".brush")
     //.call(brush.extent([minExtent, maxExtent]));          
         
    x1.domain([minExtent, maxExtent]);      
       
    //update main item rects
    rects = itemRects.selectAll("rect")
            .data(visItems, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.starting_time);})
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);});
    
    rects.enter().append("rect")
     .attr("class", function(d) {return "miniItem "+d.state;})
     .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.starting_time);})
     .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane) + 10;})
     .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return colores_background(d.lane);
     })
     .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);})
     .attr("height", function(d) {return .8 * y1(1);});

    rects.exit().remove();

    //update the item labels
    labels = itemRects.selectAll("text")
     .data(visItems, function (d) { return d.id; })
     .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(Math.max(d.starting_time, minExtent) + 2);});

    labels.enter().append("text")
     .text(function(d) {return d.text;})
     .attr("class", function(d) {return d.state;})
     .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(Math.max(d.starting_time, minExtent));})
     .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane + .5);})
     .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return colores_foreground(d.lane);
     })
     .attr("text-anchor", "start");

    labels.exit().remove();
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#holder {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*
.chart {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
*/

.timelinechart{
  /*width:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.timelinechart svg{
  width:100%;
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
}

.timelinechartg{
  
}

.mini text {
  font: 10px sans-serif; 
}

.main text {
  font: 12px sans-serif; 
}

.miniItem {
  /*fill: darksalmon;*/
  stroke-width: 6; 
}

.miniItem.future{
  fill: #448875;
}
text.future {
  fill: #f7b363;
}


.brush .extent {
  stroke: #b6b8b9;
  fill: #57585b;
  fill-opacity: .365;
  stroke-width: .2;
}

.laneImg{
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="timelinechart" data-role="timelinechart" data-width=500 data-height=300 data-data="" ></div>
```

Comment: yes - something like this - with a configuration object - https://jsfiddle.net/KgomDr/46uLtcvf/

Comment: Means? What is the issue in my result? Can you explain what exactly is missing?

Comment: Yes. This is possible. Can you store your date as a `date` object instead of timestamps?

Comment: well - I am trying to model it on possible real data - how easy is the conversion between timestamp/date object -- is it possible to add this to the config object?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m0czbuxs/2/  -- I've added the config object to the dom so its all in one place-- - need to add more classes so styles are configured in the css. I've added more data to get closer to actual data structure - but the mini holder with the scrubber still is creating vertical lines incorrectly. I've added a tooltip on this version - https://jsfiddle.net/m0czbuxs/3/

Comment: So what is wrong and what is remaining in latest fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nu1z4d3r/  -- I've cleaned up the code base -- need to clean up the way the labels are on the chart -- so it hits again the axis cleanly. Add full data ranges, I've deleted the vertical lines that were appearing in the middle chart, cleaned up the tooltip design -- it would be good to add an auto scrub option so that the timeline is fully presented with the scrubber already on

Comment: I'm trying to add this -- set brush onload feature -- https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/3cda05ca68cba260cb81

Comment: Means you want to have the custom textboxes to set the zoom? Or you want to set brush fully on load of chart?

Comment: -- well - I saw an example that has input boxes -- but I am trying to just set the zoom/brush on load -- and maybe to a specific time range a second later --- I was trying to take out the input box values -- but I am not sure how this code works to make it inline with what is on the current fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2y8gkas3/8/ - latest - cleaned up labels on left and added more classes

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558856/how-to-use-scaletime-to-horizontally-position-a-background-rectangle

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question what you mean by the **base rectangle** however, you can hide anything you don't want to see by setting opacity to 0 using `.style("opacity", 0)` for each element you'd like to hide as following (I hid pretty much everything, except for the range line which was my best guess for the **base rectangle**). You can still select and scrub on it as before:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var $this = $('.timelinechart');
    
      var w = $this.data("width");
      var h = $this.data("height");
      //var data = $this.data("data");

      
    var data = [
      {
        "label": "person a",
        "icon": "4",
        "times": [
          {"text": "Test 1", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000},
          {"text": "Test 2", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000},
          {"text": "Test 6", "starting_time": 1355761900000, "ending_time": 1355764520000},
          {"text": "Test 7", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000}
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "person b",
        "icon": "5",
        "times": [
          {"text": "Test 8", "starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000},
          {"text": "Test 9", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000},
          {"text": "Test 10", "starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355867900000}
        ]
      }
    ];


    var lanes = [];
    var times = [];
    var icons = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      lanes.push(value.label);
      //icons.push(_avatarList[value.icon].image);
      $.each(value.times, function(i, v) {
        v["lane"] = index;
      });
      times.push(value.times); 
    });

    var laneLength = lanes.length;
    var items = [].concat.apply([], times);

    $.each(items, function(i, v) {
      v["id"] = i;
    });

    var timeBegin = d3.min(items, function(d) { return d["starting_time"]; });
    var timeEnd = d3.max(items, function(d) { return d["ending_time"]; });

    var m = [25, 80, 15, 105], //top right bottom left 
      w = w - m[1] - m[3],
      h = h - m[0] - m[2],
      miniHeight = laneLength * 12 + 50,
      mainHeight = h - miniHeight - 50;

    //scales
    var x =  d3.scaleTime()
        .range([0, w])    
        .domain([timeBegin, timeEnd]);
    var x1 = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, w]);
    var y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, mainHeight])
        .domain([0, laneLength]);
    var y2 = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, miniHeight])
        .domain([0, laneLength]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
      .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
      .tickFormat(d=>d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d));


    var scaleFactor = (1/(timeEnd - timeBegin)) * (w);

    var chartWidth = w + m[1] + m[3];
    var chartHeight = h + m[0] + m[2];

    var chart = d3.select($this[0])
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", chartWidth)
          .attr("height", chartHeight)
          .attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+chartWidth+" "+chartHeight)
          .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "timelinechartg");
    
    chart.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", mainHeight);

    var main = chart.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", mainHeight)
          .attr("class", "main");

    var mini = chart.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + m[0]) + ")")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", miniHeight)
          .attr("class", "mini");


    var gX = chart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + (mainHeight + miniHeight) + ")")
          .call(xAxis); 
          
    //background colors
    function colores_background(n) {
      var colores_g = ["#f8dd2f", "#e9168a", "#448875", "#2b2d39", "#c3bd75", "#1b91dc"];
      return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
    }

    //foreground colors
    function colores_foreground(n) {
      var colores_g = ["#553814", "#311854", "#f7b363", "#c12f39", "#89191d", "#2b2d39"];
      return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
    }

    //main lanes and texts
    main.append("g").selectAll(".laneLines")
      .data(items)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", function(d) {return y1(d.lane);})
      .attr("x2", w)
      .attr("y2", function(d) {return y1(d.lane);})
      .attr("stroke", "lightgray")

        var defs = main.append('svg:defs');

    main.append("g").selectAll(".laneText")
      .data(lanes)
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) {return d;})
      .attr("x", (-m[1] + 10))
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return y1(i + .5);
      })
      .attr("dy", ".5ex")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("class", "laneText");

    //mini lanes and texts
    mini.append("g").selectAll(".laneLines")
      .data(items)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return y2(d.lane);
      })
      .attr("x2", w)
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return y2(d.lane);
      })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("stroke", "lightgray");

    mini.append("g").selectAll(".laneText")
      .data(lanes)
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) {return d;})
      .attr("x", -m[1] + 40)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {return y2(i + .5);})
      .attr("dy", ".5ex")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("class", "laneText");

    var itemRects = main.append("g")
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
        
    //mini item rects
    mini.append("g").selectAll("miniItems")
      .data(items)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) {return "miniItem "+d.state;})
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.starting_time);})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return y2(d.lane + .5) - 5;})
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colores_background(d.lane);
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return (d.ending_time - d.starting_time) * scaleFactor;
      })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("height", 10);

    //mini labels
    mini.append("g").selectAll(".miniLabels")
      .data(items)
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) {return d.text;})
      .attr("class", function(d) {return d.state;})
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.starting_time);})
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y2(d.lane + .5);
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colores_foreground(d.lane);
      })
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("dy", ".5ex");

    $.each(icons, function(index, value) {
      defs.append('svg:pattern')
        .attr('id', "--"+index)
        .attr('width', 1)
        .attr('height', 1)
        .append('svg:image')
        .attr('image-rendering', "optimizeQuality")
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet")
        .attr('xlink:href', value)
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', 50)
        .attr('height', 50);

      defs.append('svg:pattern')
        .attr('id', "--m"+index)
        .attr('width', 1)
        .attr('height', 1)
        .append('svg:image')
        .attr('image-rendering', "optimizeQuality")
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet")
        .attr('xlink:href', value)
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', 20)
        .attr('height', 20);  

      main.append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate("+(-m[1] + 5)+","+ (y1(index + .5) - 50) +")";
        })
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "user")
          .style("stroke", "gray")
          .style("fill", "url(#--"+index+")")
          .attr("r", 25)
          .attr("cx", 40)
          .attr("cy", 50);

      mini.append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate("+(-m[1] + 40)+","+ (y2(index + .5) - 20) +")";
        })
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "user")
          .style("stroke", "gray")
          .style("fill", "url(#--m"+index+")")
          .attr("r", 10)
          .attr("cx", 20)
          .attr("cy", 20);
    });

    var brush = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[0, 0], [w, miniHeight]])
        .on("brush", brushed);

    mini.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
      .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", 1)
      .attr("height", miniHeight - 1); 

    function brushed() {
      var selection = d3.event.selection;
      var timeSelection = selection.map(x.invert, x);
      //console.log("selection: " + selection);
      //console.log("start: " + timeSelection[0]);
      //console.log("end: " + timeSelection[1]);
      
      var rects;
      var labels;
      var minExtent = timeSelection[0];
      var maxExtent = timeSelection[1];    
      
      var visItems = items.filter(function(d) {return d.starting_time <  maxExtent && d.ending_time > minExtent;});
    
        //mini.select(".brush")
          //.call(brush.extent([minExtent, maxExtent]));          
          
        x1.domain([minExtent, maxExtent]);      
        
        //update main item rects
        rects = itemRects.selectAll("rect")
                .data(visItems, function(d) { return d.id; })
            .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.starting_time);})
            .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);});
        
        rects.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d) {return "miniItem "+d.state;})
          .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.starting_time);})
          .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane) + 10;})
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return colores_background(d.lane);
          })
          .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.ending_time) - x1(d.starting_time);})
          .attr("height", function(d) {return .8 * y1(1);});

        rects.exit().remove();

        //update the item labels
        labels = itemRects.selectAll("text")
          .data(visItems, function (d) { return d.id; })
          .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(Math.max(d.starting_time, minExtent) + 2);});

        labels.enter().append("text")
          .text(function(d) {return d.text;})
          .attr("class", function(d) {return d.state;})
          .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(Math.max(d.starting_time, minExtent));})
          .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane + .5);})
          .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return colores_foreground(d.lane);
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", "start");

        labels.exit().remove();
    }

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#holder {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*
.chart {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
*/

.timelinechart{
  /*width:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.timelinechart svg{
  width:100%;
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
}

.timelinechartg{
  
}

.mini text {
  font: 10px sans-serif; 
}

.main text {
  font: 12px sans-serif; 
}

.miniItem {
  /*fill: darksalmon;*/
  stroke-width: 6; 
}

.miniItem.future{
  fill: #448875;
}
text.future {
  fill: #f7b363;
}


.brush .extent {
  stroke: #b6b8b9;
  fill: #57585b;
  fill-opacity: .365;
  stroke-width: .2;
}

.laneImg{
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="timelinechart" data-role="timelinechart" data-width=500 data-height=300 data-data="" ></div>
```

Comment: no - that's not what I meant -- something more like this --  just cleaning up the base and taking out, not opacity:0 elements, https://jsfiddle.net/2mvhjr7z/2/